# NSUserDefaults setObject:nil vs. setNilValueForKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

My app crashes whenever I try the following line:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setNilValueForKey:@"my_key"];`

with this error: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '[<NSUserDefaults 0x7a2423d0> setNilValueForKey]: could not set nil as the value for the key my_key.'`

But when I do this it seems to work:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"my_key"];`

Can someone explain the difference between these 2 functions?

Comment: Surely the documentation does…!? BTW this has nothing to do with Xcode whatsoever.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I searched but did not find an explanation. If you can provide a link to the documentation that goes over the difference I will happily delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple doc : "The default implementation raises an NSInvalidArgumentException." Ovbiusly when you call it the NSInvalidArgumentException will be launched. 
You can call, but you will are launching an exception. Where use Apple this methods, well according to its doc. again: "Invoked by setValue:forKey: when it’s given a nil value for a scalar value (such as an int or float)."

Let's see a little example:

We create a new class, TestObject, we only add a couple of properties in its header (.h) file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TestObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *keyString;
@property (nonatomic) int keyInteger;

@end
```

Well, now we import it in our viewController and we add the next code to the viewDidLoad methods in order to test:

```
    TestObject *testObject = [[TestObject alloc] init];
[testObject setValue:@"Hola" forKey:@"keyString"];
[testObject setValue:@2 forKey:@"keyInteger"];

@try {
    // This is the method wich launch the exception.
    [testObject setValue:nil forKey:@"keyInteger"];

    //  If you test this the exception won't be launched.
    //  [testObject setKeyInteger:nil];

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"The exception name is %@",[exception name]);
}

NSLog(@"View values: %@\n%d",testObject.keyString,testObject.keyInteger);
```

Of course we can override this methods in our subclass, and change its behavior. 
All info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/setNilValueForKey:

Answer (score 7):

`setNilValueForKey:` is part of the `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol and is not intended to be called directly, just overridden by classes with custom `NSKeyValueCoding` implementations. `setObject:forKey:`, however, is a method provided by `NSUserDefaults` and essentially removes the key from the defaults when sent with a nil object (though this behavior may look different in Swift).

Comment: One should use `-removeObjectForKey:` to remove values, not `-setObject:forKey:` with a `nil` value.